# HTML Email - Button as a Form in an Email

Tags: html, email, forms, paypal

Wondering if it is ok to have a form inside an HTML email. All i would be doing is having an image input submit to a paypal buy page. I would like it to go right to paypal without going to a marketing page first...

I would have the whole form that paypal requires for a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to make sure the `Content-Type` of the email is set to `text/html` and the recipient's email client will have to support HTML emails, other than that I should mostly be fine.

Comment: Right, we send html and text based version of every email

Answer (score 3):

Most email clients do not support forms within them, this includes outlook 2007, ideally if you can have this as a link behind a image is better as then you will get more support across email clients.